# Typescript How to infer Combinded Types

Tags: typescript

```
interface Base<T> {
    values: T[];
}

interface HaveA<T> extends Base<T> {
    a?: number;
}

interface HaveB<T> extends Base<T> {
    b?: number;
}

interface HaveC<T> extends Base<T> {
    c?: number;
}

type SetA<V, X> = V extends Base<X> ? V & HaveA<X> : HaveA<V>;
type SetB<V, X> = V extends Base<X> ? V & HaveB<X> : HaveB<V>;
type SetC<V, X> = V extends Base<X> ? V & HaveC<X> : HaveC<V>;


type A = SetA<string, string>; // HaveA<string>, right
type AB = SetB<A, string>; // HaveA<string> & HaveC<string>, right
type ABC = SetC<AB, string>; // HaveC<string>, wrong
```

I want to make type in any combination from origin type.
like `A: {a}, B: {b}, C:{c}, AB:{a, b}, AC:{a, c}, BC:{b, c}, ABC: {a, b, c}`

used `&` operator for combine each types.
used `extends Base` to make sure that type already extended to any characters.
but It seems to not a correct operator for check for it.

how to check the `type` in `type & type`?
have there other way for combine type except using `&` ?

I solved it use `'values' in keyof V` as temporary way.
some interface may will have not 'values'.

**ADDED:**

```
interface Base<T> {
    items: T[];
}

interface A<T> extends Base<T> {
    a: number;
}

interface B<T> extends Base<T> {
    b: number;
}

interface C<T> extends Base<T> {
    c: number;
}

type Arg<T, U> = T extends null ? U : T & U;
type DataA<T> = T extends { items: Array<infer X> } ? T & A<X> : A<T>;
type DataB<T> = T extends { items: Array<infer X> } ? T & B<X> : B<T>;
type DataC<T> = T extends { items: Array<infer X> } ? T & C<X> : C<T>;


class Types<T, U> {
    set<V>() {
        return this as any as Types<Arg<T, V>, U>;
    }

    setA() {
        return this as any as Types<Arg<T, { a: number }>, DataA<U>>;
    }

    setB() {
        return this as any as Types<Arg<T, { b: number }>, DataB<U>>;
    }

    setC() {
        return this as any as Types<Arg<T, { c: number }>, DataC<U>>;
    }

    test(t: T) {
    }

    test2(f: (args: U) => void) {
        f(<U>{});
    }
}

const types = new Types<null, number>();

types
    .set<null>()
    .set<{ foo: string }>()
    .set<{ bar: string }>()
    .setA()
    .setB()
    .setC()
    .test2(d => {});
```

This is similar to my last test codes.
when I wrote question. My IDE has lag and error too.
I don't know why my IDE working correct.

I'm not a fool, maybe world hate me

Comment: When I paste your code into the playground, I get the type of `ABC` as `HaveA<string> & HaveB<string> & HaveC<string>`.  Is this not what you expected?  I don't understand the rest of the question.

Comment: Yes, I expected it. but It's not work to me. Does not infer to Base, If has the `&` operator.
I got result, but i don't know reason, I changed every flows.

Comment: Then we need to figure out what is different about your environment that is causing the code to behave differently.  What version of TypeScript are you using?

Comment: @MattMcCutchen I made wrong example codes.
Actually original type starts with `null [& {} [& {}]]`. 
I thought, if combinded types has `Base` in one of it, it will work right.
but it's wrong
Sorry for make you confuse

Comment: Can you please update the original code block to show the complete code you are using, the types you expect, and the actual types you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me [in the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Base%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20values%3A%20T%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20HaveA%3CT%3E%20extends%20Base%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3F%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20HaveB%3CT%3E%20extends%20Base%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3F%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20HaveC%3CT%3E%20extends%20Base%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20c%3F%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20SetA%3CV%2C%20X%3E%20%3D%20V%20extends%20Base%3CX%3E%20%3F%20V%20%26%20HaveA%3CX%3E%20%3A%20HaveA%3CV%3E%3B%0D%0Atype%20SetB%3CV%2C%20X%3E%20%3D%20V%20extends%20Base%3CX%3E%20%3F%20V%20%26%20HaveB%3CX%3E%20%3A%20HaveB%3CV%3E%3B%0D%0Atype%20SetC%3CV%2C%20X%3E%20%3D%20V%20extends%20Base%3CX%3E%20%3F%20V%20%26%20HaveC%3CX%3E%20%3A%20HaveC%3CV%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20A%20%3D%20SetA%3Cstring%2C%20string%3E%3B%20%2F%2F%20HaveA%3Cstring%3E%2C%20right%0D%0Atype%20AB%20%3D%20SetB%3CA%2C%20string%3E%3B%20%2F%2F%20HaveA%3Cstring%3E%20%26%20HaveC%3Cstring%3E%2C%20right%0D%0Atype%20ABC%20%3D%20SetC%3CAB%2C%20string%3E%3B%20%2F%2F%20HaveC%3Cstring%3E%2C%20wrong) (the link is too long to go in a comment).

Comment: I have reproduced the codes. Can't believe result.
I tested on WebStorm and Visual Studio Code as Certainly
even for all day. Want to see mother :( thanks again.

Comment: can you please tell me, if you know how to change `Types` in `this as any Types`
as Dynamic Constructor. I want to make Child of `Types` class that recating itself.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  Please submit a new question with a clear example of what you want the code to do that it currently doesn't do.